# How to stop "password reset" emails from Apple?

Tags: email, password

Every day or two, I get another "how to reset your AppleID password" from Apple.  They assure me my account is secure.

I've never gotten more than one of these from any other individual service, ever.  It's getting pretty annoying with the Apple ones, though.

Short of deleting my Apple account altogether, is there any way to stop this?

Answer (score 10):

I get these all the time, and it's not even Apple's fault.

If—like me—you:

- Use a me.com or mac.com email address as your Apple ID
- Have a common username (such as steve, @ either mac.com or me.com)

Then every Joe or Jane who comes along *thinks* that they have joe@mac or jane@me, can't sign in, and tells Apple to reset the password. Apple does what it should do and sends you an email telling you how to reset your password. Again. And again. And again.

If you're in the same situation, there's nothing that can be done about it (short of giving up that nice mac.com address).

Comment: Whatever the mail client you are using, you should be able to do a rule which will put this messages in a folder where you won't see them anymore or even delete them if you're sure your rule is strict enough not to also catch other messages.

Comment: @Ludo - I don't like to auto-trash anything, but otherwise, this is pretty much what I'm doing now (and why it doesn't bother me too much).

Comment: I had a very common username on Twitter and got these "password reset" emails from them almost every day. At first I thought someone was trying to hack in, but eventually I realized it was most likely stupid people who thought it was their account.

Comment: Relevant: http://xkcd.com/1279/

Answer (score 2):

If you're getting these, it might mean someone is trying to hack into your Apple account. And they don't know your password. Though they would be stupid to keep pressing the Reset link unless they're also trying to hack into your email account to get the email too. I don't assume the emails come with an IP of the computer sending the request? Maybe you could contact Apple and see if someone on an outside IP is trying to access your stuff.

Answer (score 2):

You can stop getting these emails by switching your account to two-step authentication now that iCloud and Apple ID support that. Do keep in mind, that if you receive that email, someone (or some bot / computer script) is telling Apple to begin the reset procedure for your account and if they happen to have **compromised any step in the email chain between you and Apple** - they can take control of your account.

You'll no longer have security questions to ask and Apple will never allow the password to be reset via emails from iForgot.apple.com. You'll instead get a SMS code (or iMessage) to a trusted iOS device or use your recovery key and current password to reset the password going forward.

- [Apple ID: Frequently asked questions about two-step verification for Apple ID  - http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5570](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5570)

Answer (score 1):

Check that the home page/remembered pages in one of your browsers is not the password reset URL. Is there a particular time every day that you get them?

Answer (score 1):

I got three then the next one said you've changed your password...I think my account was hacked. Another today so whoever it was us still trying!  Don't ignore the emails